# Umlaut appears on unwanted position

Tags: characters

I am using the following imports to be able to write German umlauts.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

This works just fine, but I am having trouble writing the following sentence:

> ...bezüglich "Verbrauch von Zufall" analysieren.

The output is the following, as you can write the umlaut ä using "a

> bezüglich ”Verbrauch von Zufallänalysieren.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this?
I installed texlive on Ubuntu and I'm using LaTeXila. Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes, `ü` works in some encoding but, if you need a local modification, escape the `"u` as `\"u` or `\"{u}`: this shouldn't make conflicts.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This doesn't work. Both escaping variants give me: Zufallänalysieren. But I'm starting to think this a problem of my pdf viewer (evince) as when I hover over it the ä becomes an a. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Take care of three factors (plus the package you use and I don't have any experience with): encoding, escaping and mark **`** vs. **'**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here two ways:

1. Use the `csquotes`-package and its command `\enquote` (better way)
2. Or use `''` and ``` `` ```

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
...bezüglich \enquote{Verbrauch von Zufall} analysieren.\par   
...bezüglich ``Verbrauch von Zufall'' analysieren.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this package offer any localization options? [english=quotes] as argument doesn't get me very far, neither does the minimal [manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes).

Comment: @Eurysis: You're looking for tab. 1 in the manual. It seems to be lost in the actual manual version. For english citation you have the options `american` and `british` (german manual ver 5.1)

Answer (score 1):

`"` is a shorthand character in babel and language `ngerman`. It is used to write umlauts as ASCII: `"A`, `"O`, `"U`, `"a`, `"o`, `"u`, `"s`.

Also it can be used to get the correct German quotes:

```
bezüglich "`Verbrauch von Zufall"' analysieren
```

or

```
bezüglich ">Verbrauch von Zufall"< analysieren
```

The Unicode characters are:

- Double quotation marks:
  `„`: U+201E (DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK), `` "` ``, `\glqq`
  `“`: U+201C (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK), `"'`. `\grqq`
- Single quotation marks:
  `‚`: U+201A (SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK), `\glq`
  `‘`: U+2018 (LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK), `\grq`

Also the French guillemets in the opposite direction than in French typography can be used:

- Double quotation marks:
  `»`: U+00BB (RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK), `">`, `\frqq`
  `«`: U+00AB (LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK), `"<`, `\flqq`
- Single quotation marks:
  `›`: U+203A (SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK), `\frq`
  `‹`: U+2039 (SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK), `\flq`

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% get real umlaut glyphs instead of accent constructions
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

"A, "O, "U, "a, "o, "u, "s\par
Ä, Ö, Ü, ä, ö, ü, ß

\bigskip

bezüglich "`Verbrauch von Zufall"' analysieren; \glq single\grq\par
bezüglich „Verbrauch von Zufall“ analysieren; ‚single‘

\bigskip

bezüglich ">Verbrauch von Zufall"< analysieren; \frq single\flq\par
bezüglich »Verbrauch von Zufall« analysieren; ›single‹

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Literature

- The documentation for the German shorthands can be found in [**`gerdoc`**](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/german/gerdoc.pdf). (It can be used for both: `ngerman`/`german` packages and `babel` languages.)
- Wikipedia: [International variation in quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_variation_in_quotation_marks)